# Reframing Engineering Roof Truss System for attic conversion

Tags: attic-conversion

I have a single-story home in Austin, Texas with a huge attic built using Engineering Roof Truss System. I want to do an attic conversion to have at least 1500 sq. ft. of living space in my attic.

Here's a video tour of my attic - https://youtu.be/ri5QBykX-nw

Primarily, I'm interested in learning the feasibility, best solution and a cost estimate for reframing the truss in my attic for an attic conversion. Please provide explicit details.

Other challenges for attic conversion include relocating the HVAC unit in the attic and having a strategy for plumbing so I can have a bathroom in the converted attic. Please comment on the best strategy for them.

Comment: You will need a structural engineer to even think of changing the roof trusses.  The engineer is needed to design how that roof will be change, including how the trusses can be remove and support the roof at the same time.  Your insurance will insist on it being done this way.  Might be cheaper to just addon to the house instead of changing the roof.

Comment: Pricing is always off limits, but think of this as a renovation where you remove the existing roof and add a second floor. So you're basically building a one storey house on top of your existing house. Hint: not cheap.

Comment: I'm not interested in discarding or lifting the roof for a second floor. I want to do an attic conversion so it's becomes sort of 1 1/2 story home.

Comment: I don't think that's feasible given your current roof structure.

Comment: What's the span in the direction the roof trusses run?  30', assuming they span two rooms?

Comment: you would need steel instead of wood. since nobody else will, i would spitball about 10k for paperwork, 20k for labor, and 15-40k for materials. Add 25% if done soon, during the shortages. It could double if the 1st floor/foundation isn't ideal. You might even need a new foundation, don't ask about how much that costs.

Comment: Maybe the OP will come back and share the estimate after the feasibility study. (And fwiw, my gut is 400-500k in my jurisdiction, which admittedly is among the most expensive in the country.)

Comment: Question - if I'm willing to invest $2-4K for structural design documentation and feasibility and let's say another $100K for building 800-1000 sq. ft. (initially I was thinking 1500 sq. ft.) for 3 bedrooms and 1 bathroom, are such pursuits successful? I'm young man with limited experience in this area. My family needs more space and selling this home won't find me a larger home in my area with $150K more. If you think its feasible, please share some companies offering home improvement loans at lower rates. I would want to pay for this project along with my monthly mortgage.

Answer (score 6):

That could have been a great second floor if it was framed that way. With the high pitch roof you have, it *had* high potential. In my opinion, you will be better off removing the whole roof system and reframing it from scratch. The way the trusses are configured with a 2X4 bottom cord, the restructuring needs to start from the ceiling of the original floor, up from there. In addition, to re-support the roof from the underside would be a massive undertaking.

And yes an engineered would *definitely* be involved, nobody on this forum would be able to recommend anything in the way of a relocation of this or that, in my opinion, since the whole attic needs to start over. Then things like that can go in the attic of the second floor, even though all of it is still under the roof.

It would be considered a 1 1/2 or 1 3/4 story home.

Comment: I will be getting a home improvement/remodeling company to take this project, so far very few remodeling companies in Austin, TX have an idea how to restructure the framing for attic conversion. They want me to invest $3-5K for design documents to check the feasibility. My concern is I'm paying a huge amount for a problem they may not solve it or solve ineffectively and offer me an an exorbitant quote.

Comment: Coming back to your response ...

What do you mean by "removing the whole roof system"? You mean re-frame the structure while keeping the existing roof or install a new roof with reframed structure to support an attic conversion? I want a 1 and 1/2 story home, not a 2-story since the cost for the latter is exorbitant.

Also, what would be the cost estimate for reframing the truss in my attic for an attic conversion?

Comment: You misunderestimate how exorbitantly expensive trying to turn a trussed roof into something else is. Costs are high if done right, on up to the cost of the whole house (and potentially lives) when it collapses if done wrong. Removing the roof and building a second story might well be the **least** expensive way to get to what you want.

Comment: Speaking as a professional remodeler, it's not that companies in your area don't know how to do this. They know exactly how to do this, and it's as all of us here are describing. Asking again is never going to result in a different answer. If you want to spend $3k to find out what you've gotten for free on the internet, go ahead, but you'll be out $3k and hopefully know the real price in your area for what this would cost. And that price will be gobsmackingly high, because you're (to quote a brilliant man) **building a house on top of your house**.

Comment: To clarify, it is a second story, but as far as the overall term for the type of house it would be called 1 1/2 story, since the second floor is under the roof, not more exterior walls with a roof above. Yes it would take the engineering study to even begin something like this. A truss roof has the roof load spread over the whole wall section with point loads in various places. You would need to go with a "conventional framed roof". It has its load spread over the wall section as well, but the point loads will most likely be in different places, that's where the problem lays.

Comment: To add, the whole roof comes off, as in standing in your first floor and look at the sky. Seriously, what you want to do will be VERY costly. The way you think it could be done seems to make sense, but there is no practical way to add all the needed framing, then remove the framing you don't need.

Comment: Try it this way:  You do not have a 1.5 story structure.  You have a 1 story structure with something on top of it that is not any kind of story.  You have to remove that, and build a second floor.   You might choose to put a flat roof on it and have a full two stories, or a sloping roof and get what real-estate agents call "1.5 stories" which is really two stories but one of them is smaller.   Either way you need to build for a 2nd level.  You don't have one, it doesn't matter how small the floor area is that you plan to build.

Comment: I appreciate all your insights. Thank you very very much! Now ... my question is - if I'm willing to invest

Comment: Question - if I'm willing to invest $2-4K for structural design documentation and feasibility and let's say another $100K for building 800-1000 sq. ft. (initially I was thinking 1500 sq. ft.)  for 3 bedrooms and 1 bathroom, are such pursuits successful? I'm young man with limited experience in this area. My family needs more space and selling this home won't find me a larger home in my area with $150K more.

If you think its feasible, please share some companies offering home improvement loans at lower rates. I would want to pay for this project along with my monthly mortgage.

Comment: You will need to get an engineer involved, that will be the feasibilty research. You will need to get a design/build contractor to work with the engineer to design walls in places so the bearing points can be hidden in walls that make up the layout. An architect can do the same thing, but then you will still need to get a builder on board. In some cases an architect could design an addition, then an engineer will set their structural components within the wall cavities detailed by the architect.

Comment: A little more info, since the architects and even the engineers are "in the trade", they may be able to point you out to a builder that can handle this scope of work. You may need to be made aware, it will not be possible to live in the house while all this is going on. You will need to find a rental for a few months. You should also move out your furniture and such. It may get damaged by the construction, or worse yet the weather. This site does not allow recommendations, just how to go about home improvement stuff